# Visual Studio vshost32.exe has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, java

I have developing in Visual Studio 2010 on the same machine for the past year.  Yesterday I installed the Java JDK as well as the Android SDK and since then I cannot run ANY project in Visual Studio.  I reveive the following error:

---

vshost32.exe has stopped working

Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH

Application Name: xxxMyApp.vshost.exe

Application Version:  10.0.30319.1

Application Timestamp:    4ba2084b

Fault Module Name:    ntdll.dll

Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514

Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7b96e

Exception Code:   c0000008

Exception Offset: 0004708f

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Locale ID:    7177

Additional Information 1: 62c6

Additional Information 2: 62c6367c0a4a7a6a13fec4af66486182

Additional Information 3: b338

Additional Information 4: b338e77b24caadf81f02d002dd08805e

---

I have tried enabling/disabling the hosting process, have rebuilt, have run registry cleaners, etc.

Has anyone come across something like this before?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by uninstalling both JDK and Android, reinstalling VS 2010, and then reinstalling JDK and Android again.

I am none the wiser as to why this long process needed to take place...  but it works now...